# In Gwt where the path of script(appName.gwt.js) which loads gwt app comes from?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jakarta-ee, module

I have started Gwt last week. And I was trying to create application without using sample app. So initially i have typed following line in html file(Application Name-loginAppGwt, package- LoginAppGwt)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="LoginAppGwt/LoginAppGwt.nocache.js"></script>
```

but it was not loading the gwt module. When i changed it to

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="loginAppGwt/loginAppGwt.nocache.js"></script>
```

It was working fine. 
But in one of the application which i have created using sample application of gwt, there was written(application name- testingApp, packagename- test)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="testingapp/testingapp.nocache.js"></script>
```

So , my doubt is where this name comes from like in my application loginAppGwt was correct but in sample application testingapp was correct??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module name can be manipulated via `<module rename-to="newname">`. Then the path would be `newname/newname.nocache.js`

Check if your example had something similar in it's module descriptor.

**Update:**

Loading of JS scripts is affected by filesystem case-sensitivity because scripts are loaded from files. However, GWT-RPC is handled by servlets and is always case sensitive. This is important because, GWT-RPC urls are prepended with package name which seems to be derived from  first part of script name in a host file (I just tested this).

So while the main script would be loaded on case-insensitive filesystems regardless of the script name case, the GWT RPC would only work if package names are equal.

Comment: i have this in loginAppGwt.gwt.xml

    `<module rename-to='loginappgwt'>`

but the path is same `loginAppGwt/loginAppGwt.nocache.js`???

Comment: and yes i don't know whether i am write or not, i think because of this path file appName.nocache.js is called. So, how can we rename it in that file????

Comment: On Windows (and on OS X with default settings) the urls are resolved NOT case sensitive. So `loginAppGwt` is the same as `logingppgwt`

Comment: But, beware: on Linux (where most production stuff is hosted) url are resolved case sensitive.

Comment: but using loginappgwt, it wasn't loading gwt module??

Comment: On my macbook it's not case sensitive. I just tested it - anything works (any combination of uppercase and lowercase). I can't say what was your problem at that time. Try to replicate the problem.